# GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog does nothing

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-maps-v2

I am trying to handle use cases where the user doesn't have Play set up correctly.  It seems extremely straight forward, but I can't get the dialog to do anything.  I have the following code in `onCreate` for a `FragmentActivity` that uses `Maps v2`.  I have ensured that execution does go inside the if statements.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    this.helper = (DatabaseHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);

    int googlePlayStatus = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(googlePlayStatus != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(googlePlayStatus)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(googlePlayStatus, this, googlePlayStatus).show();
        }
    } 

    //... do some stuff, such as use CameraUpdateFactory which throws NPE.

}
```

I have tried inserting the code into another activity, without the if checks, and the dialog shows just fine.

Comment: `without the if checks`. what does the if condition evaluates to ?

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry, I have checked that execution gets inside the if statements.  The `getErrorDialog` call just doesn't do anything.

Comment: are you sure you are on the ui thread at this point ?

Comment: @njzk2 I would assume so, I am in the `onCreate` method.

Comment: can you post a little more context code ?

Comment: @njzk2 Sure, just updated.

Comment: no error at all in the log ? you are not showing another dialog ? if you have an NPE short after, could it be that the dialog does not have the time to show ?

Answer (score 1):

If a i am getting it right, you are trying to get the dialog error to be shown. Try this:

**Edited:**

Ok, i was having the same problem as you some time ago, so this is the exact code i use on one of my projects. I call the 'getActivity' on 'isGooglePlayServicesAvailable' instead of passing this.

```
int checkGooglePlayServices = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
if (checkGooglePlayServices != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
    Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(checkGooglePlayServices, getActivity(), DIALOG_GET_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES);
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: That causes a compiler error, because `.show()` returns void, which you are trying to assign to a `Dialog`.